# using gsub function to change multiple values in the same column (variable) of a dataset

Tags: r

I have this column of data below:

```
data$fruits = c("apple","Orange","Banana")
```

I want to use the "gsub" function to change "apple" and "Banana" to "grape" and "mango" respectively such that new data is:

```
data$fruits = c("grape","Orange","mango")
```

I know that if I want to change only "apple", I can use:

```
data$fruits = gsub("apple", "grape", data$fruits).
```

My trouble is doing same for two or more values using "gsub"

Any help will be useful.

Comment: Try `stringr::str_replace(c("apple","Orange","Banana"),pattern = "apple|Orange",replacement = c('grape','mango'))`

Comment: I know "str_replace" works, I was wondering if I can use "gsub"

Comment: gsub is the wrong tool for this problem.

Comment: Yeah, gsub is not the right option as it only allows to place one pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we probably would use an assignment matrix `a`.

```
data <- tmp

a <- cbind(c("apple","Banana"), c("grape","mango"))
matches <- na.omit(match(a[,1], data$fruits))
data[matches, "fruits"] <- a[, 2]
data
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 fruits
# 1  1  4  7 10  grape
# 2  2  5  8 11 Orange
# 3  3  6  9 12  mango
```

If you really rely on `gsub` you could do

```
data <- tmp

invisible(apply(a, 1, function(x) data$fruits <<- gsub(x[1], x[2], data$fruits)))
data
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 fruits
# 1  1  4  7 10  grape
# 2  2  5  8 11 Orange
# 3  3  6  9 12  mango
```

but that's a bit awkward.

---

*Data:*

```
tmp <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
tmp$fruits = c("apple","Orange","Banana")
```